# How to get ID from Html table?

Tags: javascript, html

I've an Html table filled with PHP, in the first cell is my ID, in the last cell is a select box. When the user changes an option it will be updated in the database using the onchange function. But is there a way how I can know which ID is connected to the selected selection box? Because I want to send that ID with a link to my PHP file.....

This is my xmlhttp link:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","Update_plaats_ncr.php?q=" + str +"&number=" + num, true);
```

This is my table:

[image]

```
<?php
if ($result5->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "NCR number:";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "Status:";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5)) {
        $query6 = "SELECT * FROM `plaats_ncr`";
        $result6 = mysqli_query($connect, $query6);
        $ncrnummer = $row['id'];
        $jsnummer = $row['id'];

        if ($row['id']) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<a href=\"http://ncrapp.petrogas.local/UpdateNCR.php?id=$ncrnummer\">{$ncrnummer}</a>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            ?>
                <script>
                    function Plaats1(str) {

                        var num = <?php echo $jsnummer ?>;

                        if (str == "") {
                            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                            return;
                        }

                        else {
                            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            }

                            else {
                                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            }

                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                }
                            };
                            xmlhttp.open("GET","Update_plaats_ncr.php?q=" + str +"&number=" + num, true);
                            xmlhttp.send();
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <select name="plaats_ncr" class="form form-control" onchange="Plaats1(this.value)">
                    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6)): ;?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['plaats']; ?>"><?php echo $row['plaats']; ?></option>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                </select>
    <?php
        echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

So how can i put the correct ID(ncrnumber) in the VAR num?

Comment: Seeing a simple version of the HTML of the table could help us :)

Comment: Could you please provide some basic code of the HTML table so we can see how you're structuring it. We don't want to just see a image of the table. Thanks

Comment: I've added the code for the table.....hope you can read it ;)

Comment: I think they meant the rendered html structure - the one you would copy from page source for example

Comment: You either have to navigate the DOM (go up from the current element to the TR parent, and then back to the first cell inside it), or you put that info closer to where you need it to begin with (like putting the id value into a custom data attribute on the select element.)

Comment: Why are you echo'ing every HTML tag individually?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, Better? only useful info now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obtain the id, it is possible to first obtain the reference to the select element, then go up to the father tr and from there look for the first son of tr. This td contains the value of interest in the textContent property, in this case the ID. Please look at this example. From there you can build your query string that you will pass to the php file that processes the information

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('table select');

selects.forEach(select => addEventListener('change', handleChange));

function handleChange(event) {
    const element = event.target;
    const value = element.value;
    const id = getID(element);

    console.log(id, value);
}

function getID(element) {
    return element.closest('tr').children[0].textContent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Label 1</th>
          <th>Label 2</th>
          <th>Label 3</th>
          <th>Label 4</th>
          <th>Label 5</th>
          <th>Label 6</th>
          <th>Label 7</th>
          <th>Label 8</th>
          <th>Label 9</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>4931</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>
              <select name="option" id="option">
                  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>4933</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>
              <select name="option" id="option">
                  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>4934</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>
              <select name="option" id="option">
                  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td>4943</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>lorem6</td>
          <td>
              <select name="option" id="option">
                  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
              </select>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why the select isn't working on my script? selects.forEach(SELECT=> addEventListener('change', handleChange)); it keeps light gray(phpstrom)

Comment: I do not know about it. But in the example `const selects = document.querySelectorAll('table select');` expect a set of select elements. The selector could be different in your case. You could try something like `document.querySelectorAll('select')` or something relevant

Comment: did you save the file locally?

Comment: what file do you mean?

Comment: maybe you could send it by e-mail to me?

Comment: I would like to help you but I do not understand what you specifically need. please explain me

Comment: i fix the problem my self by using a function in javascript:  var table = document.getElementById('table');

                    for (var i = 1; i <table.rows.length; i++)
                    {
                        table.rows[i].onclick = function() {
                            document.getElementById("txt1").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                        }
                    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use data api like this :

```
<select name="plaats_ncr" class="form form-control" onchange="Plaats1(this)" data-rowId="<?$ncrnummer?>">
```

and get the id :

```
 function Plaats1(elem) {var rowid= elem.getAttribute('data-rowId');}
```